# How do I break, from outside of a loop in C?

Tags: c, function, loops, embedded, stm32

I have a code:

```
void core()
{
   loop
   {
   first_process();
   secound_process();
   
   process_synchronizer();
   }
some_other_job();
}
```

In the process `suynchronizer()` I evaluate synchronization and if the criterion has not beeing satisfied it will break the loop. The problem is the `break` is not allowed in that function since it's not in the loop.

```
void process_synchronizer()
{
   if(criterion)
      do something;
   else
      break;
}
```

But the `break` is not allowed there by the `c` compiler: `break statement not within loop or switch`

Comment: Simply `return` from the function: `else return;`

Comment: @DavidRanieri Yes your right thx. I can use that but if I need the codes after the loop to execute then. I think we have no option, doesn't it?

Comment: Ah, ok, you want to `break` the loop from another function, in this case you can return a boolean from this function and then `if (!process_synchronizer()) break;`

Comment: You can also consider `do { first_process(); second_process(); } while (process_synchronizer());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this:

```
void core()
{
   bool exit_flag = false
   while (!exit_flag)
   {
       first_process(&exit_flag);
       if (!exit_flag)
           secound_process(&exit_flag);
       if (!exit_flag)
           process_synchronizer(&exit_flag);
   }
}
```

Or this:

```
void core()
{
   bool exit_flag = false
   while (!exit_flag)
   {
       exit_flag = first_process();
       if (!exit_flag)
           exit_flag = secound_process();
       if (!exit_flag)
           exit_flag = process_synchronizer();
   }
}
```

Then adjust your functions to return the appropriate value. Like this:

```
bool process_synchronizer()
{
   if(criterion)
      do something;
      return false;
   else
      return true;
}
```

Comment: Good idea, thx for sharing, But I've found `if(!process_synchronizer()) break;` from comments as my answer. For completeness I suggest to consider davids comments to your answer.

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd Loops with a condition such as a boolean flag are often considered more readable than eternal loops with a `break` somewhere in the middle. It would seem that `do { ... exit_flag = process_synchronizer(); } while(!exit_flag);` might also do the trick.

Comment: @Lundin Helpfull, thanks. In my case I have also constrants of `for` but alos synchronization have other constraint on loop stability. Are you suggest still use `do while` with custom in loop counter increment? baybe `for` emphasis more on the counter and `do while` more emphasis  on both!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
bool process_synchronizer()
{
   if(!criterion) {
      return false;
   }
   some code here...
   return true;    /* No need of an else here */
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
void core()
{
   bool condition = true;

   do {
   first_process();
   secound_process();
   
   condition = process_synchronizer();
   } while (condition);

   some_other_job();
}
```

Or like this:

```
void core()
{
   while (true) {
       first_process();
       secound_process();
   
       if (!process_synchronizer()) {
           break;
   } 
   some_other_job();
}
```

Or even shorter, as @David in the comments mentioned:

```
void core()
{
   do {
       first_process();
       secound_process();
   } while (process_synchronizer());

   some_other_job();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your two "process" functions will want to return a go/no-go status, as well as the "synch" function, you don't need much code:

```
bool synchronizer() {
    bool criterion = /* to be defined */;
    return criterion;
}

void core() {
    while( proc0() && proc1() && synchronizer() )
        ; // happy

    some_other_job();
}
```

It's probably a good idea to move away from `void` functions (written to perform some feat yet unable to communicate their success/failure to the caller.)